# Excel Cell is only formatting when manually typing in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a Vlookup going.  The columns have been formatted to text on both tabs. Including using the Text to Columns.  The cells wont format till I manually enter the number in the Account Number column.  Then the Vlook up works.

What is the fix for this ?  Besides manually typing 1000+ Account numbers.

[image: Sample]

Comment: You have manual calculation activated for sure. In the Formulas tab of RibbonBar, open Calculation Options and check if Manual is selected, select Automatic

Comment: That is a negative.  Workbook calculation is set to automatic

Comment: As you can see from the green triangle in the upper left corner of the manually entered cell, the numbers are formatted as text, so, your VLOOKUP can't find them because the numbers-entered-as-text can't be found in an only-numbers list. You could copy the whole numbers column and paste-over in the same place with Paste Special - Values, and it should work

Comment: Nope. Both columns are text. I even used the text to column. To make sure.  Cause at the bottom there are Accts that start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you have leading spaces or something similar.

I would try adding a column to before your account number in the table you are looking up with =TRIM(B1) etc assuming your new column is "A" and your old column is "B".

Then in your vlook use a trim on your account number column e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A1),[reference area],[column no],FALSE)
```

The advantage of using the trim function is that it will turn any numbers to text.

(Alternatively you could use the VALUE function instead the TRIM function in both places which will turn the values into numbers but the TRIM function will support both numeric and alpha values)

Hope this helps